# imap_mail_compose creates noname attachments in android email

Tags: php, android, email, imap

I'm writing a php application that reads email messages from one mail account and forwards certain messages to another mail account.  I use imap_mail_compose() to create the message that will be forwarded.  When I am dealing with either a plain text message or an HTML message, it works just fine.  The problem lies when I have a message that has both text and HTML components to it.  The message shows up just fine in my mail reader on my computer, and also just fine when reading it through a web application.  The android email program instead shows a blank message with two attachments called 'noname'.  The original message is read just fine in the android email program, so I'm not sure what the difference is between the original message and the one I've created.  I've taken a look at the structure in both messages, as retrieved by imap_fetchstructure() and they are the same, so it appears that I am creating the message properly, but obviously I am doing something wrong.  I also checked it with a different android email program, K-9 Mail, and it works fine there.

Here's some code I use to set up the body portion that is used by imap_mail_compose().
The variable $emailMessage is from a class that pulls out all the parts of an email message. I found it at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-email-extract-inline-image-attachments/ and added a few extra items to it.

```
$bptr = 1;

// if both text and HTML parts exist
if ((strlen($emailMessage->bodyHTML) > 0) && (strlen($emailMessage->bodyPlain) > 0))
{
$hdr["type"] = TYPEMULTIPART;
$hdr["subtype"] = "alternative";
$body[$bptr++] = $hdr;
}   

// check for plain text message
if (strlen($emailMessage->bodyPlain) > 0) {
    $tpart["type"] = TYPETEXT;
    $tpart["subtype"] = "plain";
    $tpart["encoding"] = $emailMessage->plain_encoding;
$tpart["disposition.type"] = "INLINE";
if (strlen($emailMessage->plain_charset) > 0)
        $tpart["charset"] = $emailMessage->plain_charset;
    $tpart["contents.data"] = $emailMessage->encodePlain;
    $body[$bptr++] = $tpart;
}

// check for HTML message
if (strlen($emailMessage->bodyHTML) > 0) {
    $hpart["type"] = TYPETEXT;
    $hpart["subtype"] = "html";
    $hpart["encoding"] = $emailMessage->html_encoding;
    $hpart["disposition.type"] = "INLINE";
    if (strlen($emailMessage->html_charset) > 0)
        $hpart["charset"] = $emailMessage->html_charset;
    $hpart["contents.data"] = $emailMessage->encodeHTML;
$body[$bptr++] = $hpart;
}
```

So, anybody have any ideas about this?  Thank you for any help, as this has been a real stumper.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works here.  It was on the php site at: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php

> As we have been struggling with this for some time I wanted to share
>   how we got imap_append working properly with all MIME parts including
>   attachments.  If you are sending email and also wish to append the
>   sent message to the Sent Items folder, I cannot think of an easier way
>   to do this, as follows:
>
> 1) Use SwiftMailer to send the message via PHP. $message =
>   Swift_Message::newInstance("Subject goes here"); (then add from, to,
>   body, attachments etc) $result = $mailer->send($message);
>
> 2) When you construct the message in step 1) above save it to a
>   variable as follows:
>
> $msg = $message->toString(); (this creates the full MIME message
>   required for imap_append()!!  After this you can call imap_append like
>   this:
>
> imap_append($imap_conn,$mail_box,$msg."\r\n","\Seen");

So go to http://swiftmailer.org/ and use their library instead of re-inventing the wheel.